# Bitwise operations with bigz in gmp

Tags: r, bitwise-operators, gmp

I'm translating some cryptography scripts from Python to R. Python seems to handle very large integers much better than R can natively:

```
10593080468914978578954316149578855170502344604886137564370015851276669104055 >> 1
# 5296540234457489289477158074789427585251172302443068782185007925638334552027
```

But I'm aware of the `gmp` library for R, which handles them well (mostly):

```
as.bigz("10593080468914978578954316149578855170502344604886137564370015851276669104055")
```

For context, to translate these scripts I need to use bitwise operations. The problem is that these `bigz` objects are encoded as raw values, and so I can't use the base bitwise functions for them as they are incompatible.

Finding workaround for shifting bits to the left and right is straight foward, but I need something that will:

- Perform the equivalent of `bitwAnd` and `bitwOr`
- On `bigz` values
- WITHOUT losing precision.

Any ideas?

Bonus: if you can provide an interpretation of `bitwAnd` and `bitwOr` in terms of base 10 then that could work. Preferably with some example code in R, if not I can work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a slicker and faster way, but one option would be something like this...

```
library(gmp)

z <- as.bigz("10593080468914978578954316149578855170502344604886137564370015851276669104055")  
w <- as.bigz("1234874454654321549879876546351546654456432132321654987584654321321")

#express as numeric vectors of 0s and 1s
z1 <- as.numeric(charToRaw(as.character(z, b=2)))-48
w1 <- as.numeric(charToRaw(as.character(w, b=2)))-48

#normalise the lengths
mx <- max(length(z1), length(w1))
z1 <- c(rep(0, mx-length(z1)), z1)
w1 <- c(rep(0, mx-length(w1)), w1)

#then do & or | and convert back to bigz
zandw <- as.bigz(paste0("0b", rawToChar(as.raw(1*(z1 & w1) + 48))))
zorw <- as.bigz(paste0("0b", rawToChar(as.raw(1*(z1 | w1) + 48))))

zandw
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 905773543034890641004226585015137324621885921615658881499355162273

zorw
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 10593080469244079490573747058454505131838753934720683775076011957361968263103
```

Comment: I'm not bothered about performance right now, this matches the outputs returned by Python, so I'm delighted. You've made my day!